# Autosys JIL ignoring success conditions

Tags: conditional-statements, autosys, jil

I hope someone can point me in the right direction or shed some light on the issue I'm having.  We have Autosys 11.3.5 running in Windows environment. 
I have several jobs setup to launch on a remote NAS server.
I needed JOB_1 in particular to only run if another completed successfully.

Seems straight forward enough. In UI there's a section to specify Condition such as: s(job_name) as I have done and I'm assuming that ONLY if the job with name job_name succeeds that my initial job should run.

No matter what I do, when I make the second job fail on purpose (whether manually setting its status to FAILURE) or changing some of its parameters so that its natural run time causes it to fail. The other job that I run afterwards seems to ignore the condition altogether and complete successfully each time.

I've triple checked the job names (in fact I copy and pasted it from the JIL definition of the job so there are no typos), but it's still being ignored.

Any help in figuring out how to make one job only run if another did not fail (and NOT to run if it DID fail) would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is about server management software. Unless you are writing software with the autosys SDK, your question should be asked on [sf] instead.

Answer (score -1):

If both the jobs are scheduled and become active together, then this should not happen.
The way i think is, you must be force starting the other job while the first is failed. If thats the case, then conditions will not work.
You need to let both the jobs start as per schedule, or at least the other job start as per schedule while the first one is failed. In that case the other job will stay in AC state until the first one is SU.

Let me know if this is not the case, i will have to rephrase another solution then.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I attempted to follow your advice (I hope I understood you correctly).  I've modified the JOB2 on which JOB1 depends to fail and let it run on its usual time and fail naturally instead of force execute it or set any status to it in any way. 
JOB2 run, FAILED on it's own, JOB1 run afterwards still having the condition clause s(JOB2) and it run successfully. My understanding was it was not suppose to run at all, yet it did run.  How do I prevent JOB1 from running if JOB2 has status of FAILURE.  Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I still think it should not. If its still on, I would need more details on the job setup. Like are they in the same box or are two stand alone jobs. if you could get me the jil for the jobs would be more appropriate.